# Управление действиями в форме через браузер по локальной сети

Tags: c#, html, winforms, сеть, веб-сервер

Всем привет! Вот такой вопрос: у меня есть приложение WinForms на c#. Мне нужно, чтобы у пользователя была возможность управлять некоторыми действиями в этой форме через браузер. По локальной сети, естественно. То есть схема такая:
Кнопка на html странице -> обработка нажатия -> вызов метода в WinForms приложении. Как мне лучше это реализовать? Спасибо :)

Comment: Обработка нажатий на странице Html осуществляется с помощью JavaScript, который работает в "песочнице" браузера, т.е. изолирован от др.процессов в ОС, таким образом вызывать какие-то методы др.программы из браузера не представляется возможным.

Comment: Код на стороне страницы может отправлять запрос на локальный веб-сервер. Может, это можно как-либо использовать?

Comment: Ну, если на локальный веб-сервер, то..., но зачем? Зачем все усложнять и чесать правой рукой левое ухо? Опишите вашу проблему подробнее, для чего вы хотите из браузера управлять работой сторонней программы.

Comment: У меня есть достаточно объемное приложение WinForms с очень большим функционалом. Мне нужно сделать легкий доступ к некоторой информации этого приложения для любого человека в локальной сети. Также, нужно будет выполнять открытие определенных окон, при нажатии на кнопки на веб-странице

Comment: пишите asp net веб сервис

Comment: "...нужно сделать легкий доступ к некоторой информации этого приложения для любого человека в локальной сети..." - для хранения и доступа к информации из различных программ нужно использовать общий сервер СУБД. Тогда к одним и тем же данным можно будет получить доступ как из программы WinForms, так и с локального сайта компании.

Comment: То есть только веб сервисом можно? А есть еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: @Bulson Информация немного другого плана: например, значение некоторых текстовых полей

Comment: Работать с HTML кодом страницы - не благородное дело и как по мне является костылем. Да, бывают случаи, когда нельзя получить данные иными методами, но в 90% случаем работа идет отправкой POST/GET запросов на сервер, в том числе и форма - вы должны понять, что отправляет браузер на сервер и куда и сделать тоже самое в программе. Если это ваше Web приложение, то вы должны создать что то для работы с ним (некоторые API методы), но не как не эмулировать работу браузера!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать класс *HttpListener* в приложении и *XMLHttpRequest*-запросы в браузерном javascript. Допустим, мы хотим создать веб-интерфейс для своего приложения, который может выполнять определенные команды. Для этого нам нужно создать *HttpListener*, привязанный к какому-то локальному URL, в фоновом потоке. Этот поток будет разбирать параметры URL, выполнять необходимые действия и отправлять ответ. На клиентской стороне в браузерном JS будем считывать данные из input и отправлять асинхронный запрос к нашему серверу с соответствующим параметром.

В примере ниже сервер реагирует на два URL: на `/myapp/index.aspx` отдается веб-интерфейс, а `/myapp/command.aspx?command=...&argument=...` используется для отправки команд. Для того, чтобы все это взлетело, приложение должно запускаться либо с учетной записи администратора, либо нужно предварительно открыть порт для простых пользователей выполнением следующей команды в командной строке администратора:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ sddl=D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-2-0)
```

(Идентификатор S-1-2-0 соответствует группе всех локальных пользователей). Также возможно понадобится добавить программу в исключения фаервола и т.п. Для отладки можно заменить + на localhost, тогда можно будет работать с локального компьютера без необходимости установки ACL.

Код C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsTest1
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string htmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("frontend.html");

        void Print(string text)
        {
            if(text==null)text = "";
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                textBox1.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;
            }));
        }

        void CloseWindow()
        {            
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                this.Close();
            }));
        }

        //метод для серверного потока
        public void RunServer()
        {            

            // Create a listener.
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            // Add the prefixes.
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8080/myapp/");
            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
                string url = request.RawUrl;                                 

                HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
                // Construct a response.

                if (url.StartsWith("/myapp/index.aspx") == false && url.StartsWith("/myapp/command.aspx") == false)
                {
                    //вернуть ошибку при неверном URL
                    response.StatusCode = 404;
                    response.StatusDescription = "Not found";
                    response.Close();
                    continue;
                }

                //разбираем параметры запроса
                string command = request.QueryString["command"];
                string argument = request.QueryString["argument"];
                string responceString = "";

                if (url.StartsWith("/myapp/index.aspx"))
                {
                    responceString = htmlString;  //вернуть веб-интерфейс                  
                }
                else
                {
                    //обработать команду
                    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(command)) command = "help";
                    if (argument == null) argument = "";
                    switch (command)
                    {
                        case "print": Print(argument); responceString = "OK"; break;
                        case "help": responceString = "Commands: print, close, help"; break;
                        case "close": CloseWindow(); responceString = "OK"; break;
                        default: responceString = "Unknown command"; break;
                    }
                }

                byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responceString);

                // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
                response.Headers.Add("Expires: Tue, 01 Jul 2000 06:00:00 GMT");
                response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate");
                response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
                System.IO.BinaryWriter wr = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(output);
                using (wr)
                {
                    wr.Write(buffer);
                }

            }            
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //запускаем серверный поток
            System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(RunServer);
            th.IsBackground = true;
            th.Start();            
        }            
    }    
}
```

Файл frontend.html:

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript">

function reqReadyStateChange() {

    if (window.xhr.readyState == 4) {   
        var status = window.xhr.status; 

        if (status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('ta').value = window.xhr.responseText;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('ta').value = window.xhr.statusText;
        }
    }
}

function request(url){
    document.getElementById('ta').value = '';
    window.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = reqReadyStateChange;
    xhr.send(); 
}

</script></head>
<body><form> 
  Command: <input type="text" id="inpCommand"/><br/>
  Argument: <input type="text" id="inpArgument"/><br/>
  <input type="button" 
         onClick="request('/myapp/command.aspx?command='+document.getElementById('inpCommand').value+'&amp;argument='+document.getElementById('inpArgument').value);" 
         value="Execute"/>
  <br/><br/>
  <textarea id="ta" rows = "10" cols = "45"></textarea>
</form></body></html>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!

Comment: Все работает! Еще раз огромное спасибо!