# Создание HTTP соединения в локальной сети

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование

При создании POST запроса к компьютеру, находящемуся в локальной сети я получаю следующую ошибку:

> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

Код выполнения запроса:

```
string httpAddress = "http://192.168.1.101:8080/";
var Client = new HttpClient();
Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(httpAddress);

while (true) {
    Console.Write("Send: ");
    Console.WriteLine(Client.PostAsync(httpAddress,
        new StringContent(Console.ReadLine(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result.StatusCode);
}
```

На другой стороне соответственно:

```
HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/");
httpListener.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Wait...");

while (true) {
    var context = httpListener.GetContext();
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
        context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
        Console.WriteLine("Data: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Почему я не могу указать в HTTP-адресе локальный IP-адрес?

Если запустить этот код в одной системе и указать адрес подключения как `localhost:8080`, всё работает исправно. Если указать `127.0.0.1:8080`, возникает такая же ошибка.

Comment: `httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.1.101:8080/");`

Comment: Получается для этого `HttpListener` должен знать свой локальный IP. Откуда взять эту информацию?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36857268/12888024

Comment: @aepot _`httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.1.101:8080/");`_ - В случае с глобальным IP-адресом ситуация аналогичная?

Comment: Почему вообще не получается использовать `localhost` в HTTP-адресе?

Comment: `localhost` = `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Я понимаю. Почему не получается использовать это и приходится указывать свой IP-адрес?

Comment: localhost не получается по той же причине, что и 127.0.0.1, потому что слушать вам надо реальный сетевой интерфейса, а 127.0.0.1 - виртуальный, для обращения к себе.

Comment: @aepot Должен ли сервер всегда отвечать на каждое сообщение клиента? У меня получается, что вызов `PostAsync` просто зависает. По идее нужно, чтобы клиент просто отправлял серверу сообщения, а тот их получал.

Comment: `просто зависает` используйте `await` вместо `.Result`, для начала. Да, сервер должен отвечать, так устроен протокол HTTP. Можете ответить 204 No Content, если сильно не хочется отправлять payload в ответе.

Comment: Чтобы просто слушать на любом локальном адресе есть особый префикс +: `listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8080/");`. Но есть тонкости, чтобы слушать на внешних адресах, нужны определенные права доступа. См. например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/826203/240512